# How to print Nodes while showing ProgressIndicator?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, task, javafx-8

### How to implement Tasks in JavaFx, that depend on GUI components ?

The goal is to generate a report from various SceneGraph components while presenting the user with some ProgressIndicator.

We need to

1. Generate a snapshot of some Node
2. Convert it to an BufferedImage
3. Pass the image along to the report generating engine

Since one cannot update the GUI unless from the FxThread, the problem becomes :

*How to show progress indicators for long running GUI operations?*

My first approach of simply putting the logic into a [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) obviously failed resulting in a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application` upon execution of the [snapshot method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-).
It contains a [Fx thread check](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/javafx/scene/Node.java#Node.snapshot%28javafx.util.Callback%2Cjavafx.scene.SnapshotParameters%2Cjavafx.scene.image.WritableImage%29) which I assume means it will not be possible to just temporarily remove the Node from the Scene.

Using [Platform.runLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) is also insufficient since it can only be used to **write** data to the GUI, but not **read**. (Or can it?)

For a short time I evaluated using a SwingWorker but found it offered no benefit whatsoever compared to a Task.

Even if we ignore the read/write problem for a second. Consider this example:

```
package com.isp.lpt.progress;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.LongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleLongProperty;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GuiTaskExample extends Application
{
  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
  private final static int    WIDTH  = 100;
  private final static int    HEIGHT = 100;

  @Override
  public void start( final Stage primaryStage )
  {
    final Group root = new Group();
    final Group circleGroup = new Group();
    final ProgressIndicator indicator = new ProgressIndicator();
    root.getChildren().add( circleGroup );
    root.getChildren().add( indicator );
    final Scene scene = new Scene( root );

    final GuiTaskExample that = this;
    final Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>()
    {
      @Override
      protected Void call() throws Exception
      {
        try (final IntStream intStream = RANDOM.ints( 1, HEIGHT ))
        {
          final long maxSize = HEIGHT * WIDTH;
          final Stream<Circle> circles = intStream.mapToObj( that::createCircleThing ).limit( maxSize );

          //local variables must be final for lambdas
          final LongProperty counter = new SimpleLongProperty( 1 );

          circles.forEach( circle ->
          {
            updateProgress( counter.get(), maxSize );
            counter.set( counter.get() + 1 );
            Platform.runLater( ( ) -> circleGroup.getChildren().add( circle ) );
          } );

          return null;
        }
      }
    };

    indicator.progressProperty().bind( task.progressProperty() );

    task.setOnSucceeded( done ->
    {
      root.getChildren().remove( indicator );
      primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    } );

    task.exceptionProperty().addListener( ( observable, oldValue, newValue ) -> newValue.printStackTrace() );
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute( task );

    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private Circle createCircleThing( final int radius )
  {
    final Circle circle = new Circle();
    System.out.println( radius );
    circle.setRadius( RANDOM.nextInt( radius ) );
    circle.setCenterX( circle.getRadius() + RANDOM.nextInt( WIDTH ) );
    circle.setCenterY( circle.getRadius() + RANDOM.nextInt( HEIGHT ) );
    circle.setStrokeWidth( RANDOM.nextDouble() * 4 );
    circle.setStroke( randomPaint() );
    circle.setFill( randomPaint() );
    circle.setEffect( new DropShadow( RANDOM.nextInt( 12 ), randomPaint() ) );
    return circle;
  }

  private Color randomPaint()
  {
    return Color.rgb( RANDOM.nextInt( 255 ), RANDOM.nextInt( 255 ), RANDOM.nextInt( 255 ),
        RANDOM.nextDouble() );
  }

  public static void main( final String[] args )
  {
    launch( args );
  }
}
```

The example creates a whole lot of GUI elements in a task, then draws it to the screen, but (at least on my machine) drawing to the screen is what takes the longest and I would like to hide behind a progress indicator.

So the question becomes:
**How can you draw to an offscreen buffer in JavaFx?**

I am open to suggestions to both the very general case of long running GUI manipulations in Fx and/or to our specific use case on using snapshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the report part, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14841487/3956070) solves your problem. The refered link is broken, but you can find it [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/10685099#10685099).

Basically, he uses three subtasks, one to create the charts (or any other `Node` you need) in an off screen scene graph. Other to take snapshots of each chart to an JavaFX image and a third one to export the JavaFX images to files. Or alternatively you could just pass those images to your report engine.

Comment: Note the code for that example is also posted as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5072743) (just may be a more convenient way to study it)

Comment: Thank you, this definitely is a step forward. The main idea of the solution you linked to is to block on the background thread until the Platform.runLater runnable returns (using a CountdownLatch). This has at least the benefit, that the full amount of required time for the task is bound to the progressProperty. But we still have to be careful to spend enough time on the background thread so that the FX-Thread can both update the ProgressIndicator and our computation. This leads to stuttering of the GUI. Bettern than full freeze.

Comment: The revised example, using CountdownLatch: https://gist.github.com/flasheater/54ef3373623212b6b4ca

Comment: Your revised example looks good now. However, you talk about stuttering, which can be seen at the final stage of the task (70%+, in my case 8 cores, 32GB RAM...), due to the continuos load of circles up to 10000 to the scene... If you start removing previous nodes (keeping a reasonable size of 1000 nodes), it goes really smooth.

Comment: I deliberatly picked 10000 because the talk http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddJpDi5SWFc about JavaFx performance suggests, that "normal" desktops shpuld be able to handle as many nodes. Your machine (and mine) clearly are over-spec'ed to be called normal ;). But I have a usable solution now, thank you.

Comment: Good to know. This test is good for benchmarking, but I guess your reports won't have so many nodes.