# Javafx: any way to pre-render charts for future use?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Most googling results in the "OffScreenOffThreadCharts" example, but I dont think this answers my question. That performs a specific function (i.e., taking snapshots and exporting them) offscreen, whereas I need to be able to render a graph off screen and then utilize it.

I'm looking to render a chart with around 10000+ points. I've done all the loading of the ObservableLists that the chart is based off and adding them to series on separate threads, but when the chart is actually being DRAWN TO THE SCREEN the entire application seems to freeze, no matter what level of multi-threading I do. I assume this is because it is having trouble drawing this many points to the screen.

It hangs for about 3 seconds. This hang would be acceptable, if all the UI elements on the screen did not also freeze, and the entire application to hang.

I see two possible routes forward:

1) Is there any way to render this chart "in the background", and then display it once it is complete?

2) If not, is there any way to have the various UI elements continue to function while the rendering is happening?

Thank you,

Comment: possible solution:
1. render in another thread
2. take a snapshot
3. show it
4. Profit!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232578/rendering-javafx-2-charts-in-background

Comment: How would i "render in another thread"? Are there any examples that show this simply? All the examples I have found are all about loading the data on another thread, but none about actually DISPLAYING the graph. That linked example only seems to work because there is work being done on the charts... the snapshot, which isn't displayed as an actual chart... I'd like to have my chart be a normal chart after it has been loaded - so perhaps switching the scene to it, or adding it to the current scene after it has been loaded.

Comment: Without seeing any code, it's difficult to see what your issue may be. But, @James_D Offers advice in a comment on [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850211/performance-issue-with-javafx-linechart-with-65000-data-points) that may be helpful to you. Otherwise, consider the accepted answer to the thread.